# Load JCKES keystore using SunJCE provider on IBM JDK

Tags: java, keystore, jce, ibm-jdk

I am trying to load JCKES keystore which is using SunJCE provider in my application which is running IBM JDK 8 (power linux).

To enable my application to load keystore, I have done below steps:

- Extracted sun package from oracle jdk's rt.jar, created sun.jar with extracted package and added sun.jar in IBM JDK lib ext folder.
- Copied sunjce_provider jar from oracle JDK to IBM JDK lib ext folder.
- Sun jars are taken from oracle JDK installed on windows.
- Added com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE provider in java.security file of IBM JDK.

**Please let me know what more changes are needed to load the keystore.**

*Here is the code which is trying to load the keystore:*

```
    File file = new File(keystorelocation);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    ks.load(is, password);
```

However, my application fails to start with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com/sun/crypto/provider/SunJCE illegally accessing "package private" member of class sun/security/provider/SunEntries
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.putEntries(SunJCE.java:128)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.<init>(SunJCE.java:111)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:2038)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:233)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:218)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:682)
```

If I remove SunJCE provider entry from java.security file, application starts successfully, but I get below error while trying to load keystore:

```
Invalid secret key format
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1456)
```

And If I do not add any Sun jars in IBM JDK, I get below error while trying to load keystore:

```
java.io.IOException: com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1456)
```

Thanks!